# PyBugz Bash Variables \n newline is ignored

Tags: python, bash, variables, newline, pybugz

i have a bash script, that extracts the bugs from a csv file and imports it into bugzilla using PyBugz.

The following sequences are used:

```
description=$(echo "$line" |cut -f5 -d ';')
bugz -d 3 -b http://bugzilla/bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi -u "$user" -p "$pass" post --product "$prod" --component "$compo" --title "$title" --description "$description" --op-sys "$ops" --platform "$platf" --priority ""$prio"" --severity "$sever" --alias "$alias" --assigned-to "$assign" --cc "$ccl" --version "$ver" --url "$url" --append-command "$appen" --default-confirm "y"
```

but the description line containing "blablabla \n blablabla" including the newline is beeing recognized as

"Description : blablabla n blablabla"

If I export a bug and dump the output into a textfile, pybugz puts a 0x0a as newline character. how can I make pybugz recognize my \n character as 0x0a??

Comment: What is in `$description` exactly? Does it contain `\n`? If you run `bugz` manually with a description of `foo \n bar` does it work? Does a description of `foo \\n bar` work?

Answer (score 0):

If description contains the characters <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>, and you want to convert that into an actual newline, then you'll have to do some work:

```
bugz ... --description "$(echo -e "$description")" ...
```

That will expose other escape sequences as well, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-echo

Comment: Hi, thanks for this advise. Yes the file really contains 0x5c 0x6e as a sequence. with your code pybugz appears to do the same. Maybe thats how the python program reads the command line?? BTW: if I use a manual variable that really contains a newline, the python program recognizes the new line correctly.

Comment: The `-e` option for bash's echo builtin is supposed to interpret 0x5c 0x6e and give you 0x0a -- compare `echo "foo\nbar" | od -t x1` vs `echo -e "foo\nbar" | od -t x1`

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

The way to catch the data was done in the following way:

```
while read line ; do
description=$(echo "$line" |cut -f5 -d ';')
done <csvfile
```

however, the read already changed the \n string to n 
so whatever I did after that was obviously a failure.

I did it in a very unnice way now but it works like a charm

```
lines=$(cat csvexport |wc -l)
for (( lineno=1 ; $lineno<=$lines ; lineno++ )); do
description=$(cat csvexport |sed -n "$lineno"p |cut -f5 -d ';')
done
```

and everything is fine ;-)
Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: you want `read -r` so the backslash does not get swallowed. The idiomatic "iterate a file by lines" in bash is `while IFS= read -r line; do ... ; done < file`